# The forum needs a tag for Windows 2019 Server!

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tagging, tag-creation

I have a question about my Database Administrators Stack Exchange post: [MySQL Workbench, Windows Server 2019, MySQL not showing Performance, Information of MySQL Schemas!](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254290/mysql-workbench-windows-server-2019-mysql-not-showing-performance-information)

I tried to use the tag windows-server-2019 but it does not exist. I would like to propose creating it. I can't do this on my own since I don't have the necessary reputation. It will undoubtedly become more and more necessary as more people upgrade so why not do it now?

Comment: Why do you think the Windows version is even relevant to your question?

Comment: Because that's where I found the issue? Why else? In any case, whether my particular problem is specific to Windows 2019 Server **or not**, there still should be a tag for it. There are tags for Server 2003, 8, 12 and 16, so now that there's a 2019, there **should** be a tag!

Answer (score 10):

The question doesn't make an explicit case for the new tag, beyond continuing the line of existing Windows Server version tags. So, this seems like a good time to look at the utility of the whole hierarchy.

[The FAQ describes the reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041) for tagging questions:

> - Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.
> - Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories.
> - They are used for (weak) statistics.
> - Tags are used in searching.
> - Tags can award badges.

It also says what tags **are not for**:

> - Tags are not for summarizing your question.
> - Tags are not for indexing your question.

The most important of the positive reasons is to **connect experts with questions** they can answer. Now this site isn't for questions about operating systems *per se*, but I suppose there are times when it is useful to be able to find questions that apply to Windows as opposed to say Linux.

Judging from the number of followers for the existing tags, this is not very common:

- [windows-server-2003](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2003) 9 questions, zero watchers
- [windows-server-2008-r2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2008-r2) 78 questions, zero watchers
- [windows-server-2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012) 94 questions, zero watchers
- [windows-server-2012-r2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012-r2) 51 questions, zero watchers
- [windows-server-2016](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2016) 31 questions, zero watchers
- [windows-server-core](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-core) 5 questions, zero watchers

The parent tag [windows-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server) has 111 questions (17 this year) with 3 watchers. The top level tag [windows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) has 535 questions (39 this year) with 12 watchers. Only these two tags have an excerpt.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **It seems that the Windows Server version tags are noise (on this site) and should all be made synonyms of [windows-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-server).**

One could go further and argue that all Windows OS tags (client and server) should be synonyms of [windows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows).

Like many sites, we have too many largely useless tags here. This is mostly the company's fault for making tag creation too easy and not providing better tag management tools (even to moderators).

Comment: It would be great if there were better tag management tools.  Better how?  I'm not sure 

Comment: @MaxVernon Well it would easier to get rid of minor, useless tags for a start. Editing every question to remove the tag can be a little bit disruptive to the home page,

Comment: I imagine meta.se has many many questions suggesting changes 

Comment: There [might be a couple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btags%5d%20%5bfeature-request%5d%20moderator*) yeah

Answer (score -2):

You can [create tags at 300 reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). If you feel strongly about it, the thing to do is keep participating in good faith on the network until you've gained 300 rep. Then you can create the tag yourself.

At that point, if you feel the tag improves the quality or discoverability of other questions, you can add the tag to each of them for [+2 rep](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) [per approved edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256024/the-editing-reputation-limit).

Until then though, the current consensus among tag-creating users appears to be that this tag just isn't needed yet.